# How can we center a position without the text

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, center

How can we center a position without the text in align* environment inside the intertext?
If we center by:

```
\begin{align*}
    \intertext{\centering word1 word2 word3 word4}
\end{align*}
```

We get position + text centered:

```
 word1 word2 word3
       word4
```

But How can we get only position centered without text (word4 from left instead center of second line):

```
 word1 word2 word3
 word4
```

Comment: Depending on the expected output, the actual contents and the intended use case, something like `\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{l}
 word1 word2 word3\\
 word4
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}` could get you started.

Comment: @leandriis can you please give solution for align* + intertext (real case have much more details).

Comment: Your example currently only seems to contain dummy text but no math,  so why do you want to use `align` here?

Comment: @leandriis because real case contain multi lines of complicated equations, therefore I have to use align*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`align*` is for aligning multiple lines of math equations, for example to have `=`-signs go right underneath each other. It's not for normal text alignment. For that you have `\raggedright`, `\centering`, `\raggedleft` or the corresponding for environments: `\begin{flushleft}`, `\begin{center}`, `\begin{flushright}`. Or `\justifying` for justified text.

But, if you were really after this text alignment within the math `align*` environment, this is what you asked for:

[image: Align with centered intertext]

```
\begin{align*}
    x &= \sqrt{z^2 - y^2} + \leaders\hbox{.}\hskip6cm\relax\\
    \intertext{\centering\parbox{0.6\linewidth}{
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Praesent condimentum dui eget
        fringilla cursus.
    }}
    &= 3
\end{align*}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vincent Kuhlmann, can we use other dynamic way instead static size of \parbox{5cm}?

Comment: @Ben Yes you can. For example `\linewidth` is the whole width of the current column (often paperwidth-margins), and you can use a fraction, like `0.6\linewidth` (60% of the linewidth).

Comment: That's the nicer way to do things, but for demonstration purposes I showed an absolute value, so you saw that was the place controlling the width

Comment: There was a comment, now removed, saying you could do it without `\intertext`. That's right. You need to do `\noalign{\centering\parbox{...}{...}}\\ ` then. And you might need to add extra vertical space. Would be something to consider if you want less vertical spacing.

Comment: I try 0.6\linewidth but without success, can you please update the code in your answer with \linewidth?

Comment: @Ben Updated. Can you try again?